# How to make .js variables accessible to .ejs files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, template-engine

I have an index.js file and a list.ejs file, which i told the express file to include:

**index.js**:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs"); //Express Template Engine = embedded js
app.set("views", __dirname + "\\views");

let varToUseInEJS = 5;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Path of Request: " + req.path);
    res.render("list");
});

app.listen(8080, "localhost", 1, () => {
    console.log("Example app listening on: 127.0.0.1:8080");
})
```

list.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
        <% for(let i = 1; i < varToUseInEJS; i++) { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= i %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

when i change the "varToUseInEJS" to for example 5, it works and shows a table with 1 to 5 + header, but in this case, node.js debugger gives me the following error:

```
>> 9|         <% for(let i = 1; i < varToUseInEJS; i++) { %>
10|             <tr>
11|                 <td>
12|                     <%= i %>
varToUseInEJS is not defined
```

is there any way to make all .js files' variables automatically visible to ejs files?

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you want to pass data into the template variables, pass an object as the second parameter of `res.render` - see [the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will pass in `varToUse` to the sheet. Note the second parameter is just a JS object.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('list', {'varToUse': 5});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the **key** varToUseInEJS refers to the .ejs file ... and ... the **value** varToUseInEJS refers to the .js file

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('list', {varToUseInEJS: varToUseInEJS});
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and be more clear? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To generalise on @Francisco, you could also pass in `varToUseInEJS` as a variable. Just make sure that the name of the variable that you pass in `res.render()` matches the names in your EJS expressions.

```
`app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('list', {'varToUseInEJS': varToUseInEJS});
}`
```